# How to recall previous system.out.print statement after validation

Tags: java, system.out

I am trying to call a function that will validate user input so that it is between 0 and 1000. I am fine with this, but say I enter the wrong input for February and I call the validate_input() method to check this, what would I add to my else statement to recall this. This could be really simple but I haven't used Java in a long time and cannot remember how this is done. Is there a function of some sort that can be used?

```
private static void validate_input(int check_month){
        int month=check_month;
        if(month<0 && month>1000){
            System.out.println("Rainfall must be between 0-1000");
        }
        else{

        }

    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter rainfall for 12 months:");

        System.out.print("January: ");
        int january=keyboard.nextInt();
        validate_input(january);
        System.out.print("February: ");
        int february=keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("March: ");
        int march=keyboard.nextInt();
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What does "what would i add to my else statement to recall this" mean?

Comment: No, there's no standard way to do that. Essentially, system out writes to a console or  a file.

Comment: say the console prints: January- then i enter 2300, i am going to call the validate_input() method to ensure this is between 0-1000, if not i want to print out "January" again until the user enters the correct value

Comment: No need for an else statement. Just use a `while(month<0 && month>1000)` instead of `if(month<0 && month>1000)`

Comment: You need a loop construct

Comment: But you have to add the data input inside the while!

Comment: how do i keep outputting january with the use of a while statement

Comment: 'month' is not a good name for a variable that represents an amount of rainfall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "recall" the previous prompt. You can return a `boolean` from your method, and create a loop in your `main`. Also, you need a logical `||` instead of an `&&` (because no number is less than 0 and greater than 1000). Something like,

```
private boolean validate_input(int check_month){
    int month=check_month;
    return(month<0 || month>1000);
}
```

and then in `main` something like

```
int january;
do {
    System.out.print("January: ");
    january=keyboard.nextInt();
} while (!validate_input(january));
```

Comment: any idea were i would add "Please enter value between 0-1000"